# Proving $f(x)=||x||^\gamma\in D^r(\mathbb R ^n)$ for $r<\gamma$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(x)=||x||^\gamma,\quad\gamma\in2\mathbb N+1$. prove that for $r<\gamma,f(x)\in D^r(\mathbb R^n)$.

I tried dividing the question to cases. I proved that if $n=1$ $f(x)=|x|^\gamma$ is differentiable using limits. with $n>1$ I encountered a problem. First I proved using induction that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}||x||^{\gamma}=\gamma\left\Vert x\right\Vert ^{\gamma-2}x_{j}$$. here again I splitted r to cases.for $r=1$ I wrote $$Df={\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}dx_{i}}
 $$ and i assume the differntial exists since the partial derivatives exist too (and they are in the form written above). but for $r>1$ I don't know how to prove $D^rf$ exists. How can I do so?

Comment: Can you explain your notation $D^r(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

Comment: $f\in D^r(\mathbb R^n)\Leftrightarrow\text{all derivatives from order r exist in}\mathbb R ^n$

Comment: The standard notation is $C^r(\mathbf{R}^n)$.

Comment: in lecture we used the notation $C^r(R^n)$ for all derivatives of order r exist and continuous and $D^r(R^n)$ for the derivatives exist but not necessarily continuous.